# Best way to update an existing list in RavenDB using C#/MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ravendb

I have a Document class:

```
public class Document
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public String PropertyOwnerId { get; set; }
    public List<string> Files { get; set; }

    public Document()
    {
        this.Files = new List<string>();
    }
}
```

The user will upload files and the file names get stored in a loop.

```
foreach (var file in documents)
{
  model.Files.Add(fileName);
}
```

That's all standard and works fine and I end up with a document that looks like this:

```
{
    "OwnerId": "ApplicationUsers/1",
    "Files": [
        "File1.pdf",
        "Another File.pdf"
    ]
}
```

Now, when I want to add more file names to an existing document (or delete files names from the existing document), do I have to persist the existing file names in a hidden element or is there some sort of update command that RavenDB has that would allow for persisting the existing document and adding values conditionally to this Files element?

As a point of reference, what's the best way to "stuff" a list into a hidden element? This doesn't throw an error:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Files)
```

But it puts "System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]" in the hidden element, because it's obviously not a string, it's a list.

Since I've never worked with RavenDB before I'm unclear about best practices here, and after skimming a couple of RavenDB books, surprisingly, I didn't see anything that seemed to correspond to this basic task at hand.

I hope I explained what I'm trying to do well enough.

Comment: Are you using RavenFS to store the files themselves? Because if so, I'd advise you store the DocId in the file metadata to which the given file belongs -- way easier to maintain it like that imo. (Imagine for example, that FS and RavenDB run on a different server, and the FS server goes offline. Then you would have to undo the actions yourself, whereas if the doc id is in the file metadata and the save fails then you wouln't have to undo anything since nothing since nothing would get saved in the first place).

Comment: No, I'm using Amazon S3 to store the files. That's something I've done in other applications. No issues with that part. I'm just trying to ascertain the best practices for updating lists. Do you stuff the list in a hidden field, or use multiple hidden fields? Can you update a partial document or do you have to update the entire document? I've tried updating a partial document and the other values get erased.

Comment: `@Html.HiddenFor()` creates an `<input type="hidden" ../>` - and input can only hold one value, not a collection. You need to create an input for each item in the collection -

Answer (score 0):

For my situation, to create multiple hidden inputs all named "files" works perfectly:

```
foreach (var item in Model.Files)
{
   <input type="hidden" name="files" value="@item" />
}
```

Still doesn't seem to be a very elegant way to handle list types.